# Reactive Forms/ Angular Material dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

Возможно банальный вопрос, просто из головы вылетело как решить. 
Есть модальное окно в которое может передатся данные изначально либо нет. В зависимости от присуствия данных, в FormControl может быть определен formState либо нет. Проблема состоит в том, что когда модалка вызывается без передачи данных, вылазит ошибка (Cannot read property 'name' of null).

Вот код модального окна с инициализацией fromGroup:

```
 constructor(
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PositionModalComponent>,
private fb: FormBuilder,
@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
```

}

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  private buildForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: [this.data.name || '', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), EmptyValueValidator.validate]],
      cost: [this.data.cost || '', [Validators.required, NumbersValidator.onlyPositiveNumbers]]
    });
  }
```

У меня есть решение одно в голове, но это придется делать через if(data)и в зависимости от этого инициализировать разный fromGroup то есть 2 раза. Есть ли какое нибудь более лаконичное решение, без написания 2 раза одного и того же самого кода?

Comment: чувак, давай по порядку. `@Optional` тебе не нужно потому что `data` по дефолту `null` (если ты ничего не передаешь при создании модалки, материал под капотом сеттит `null`). Просто дай ему значение по умолчанию в виде объекта `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data = {}`

Comment: @overthesanity Спасибо за ответ. Твое решение было почти верным, я по дефолту определил дату в конфиге диалогового окна перед его открытием. В общем спасибо, натолкнул на мысль:)